# How do I get the current text from a QcomboBox with PyQt5 using a button?

Tags: python, pyqt5

Funny that this isn't better documented. But basically I'm just trying to get the value of a dropdown QComboBox in PyQT5 when I click a button.
Currently, when I use the following code, it is only giving me the value after I select a value in the dropdown.  I am new to PyQt.

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

def __init__(self):
    super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
    self.lineEdit = QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
    self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")

    self.templatetype = QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
    self.templatetype.setObjectName("templatetype")
    self.templatetype.addItem("Tracks")
    self.templatetype.addItem("Observations")
    self.templatetype.activated[str].connect(self.change_text)

    self.btn = QPushButton(self.centralwidget)        
    self.btn.setObjectName("btn")
    self.btn.clicked.connect(self.change_text)


def change_text(self,text):        
    self.lineEdit.setText(text)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I completely understood your question. You just want to get the text that is in the `QComboBox` when you click on the button? If that is the case then it's pretty simple. First you need to get the current text in the `QComboBox` then put it in the `QLineEdit`. Your don't need the to use a Signal here. So you can remove the following line:

```
self.templatetype.activated[str].connect(self.change_text)
```

And update your `change_text` method like this.

```
def change_text(self):
    current_value = self.templatetype.currentText()        
    self.lineEdit.setText(current_value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution...

```
self.templatetype.activated[str].connect(self.change_text)
```

should be

```
self.templatetype.highlighted[str].connect(self.change_text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
from PyQt5 import Qt

class MainWindow(Qt.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        self.main_widget = Qt.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.main_widget)
        layout = Qt.QVBoxLayout(self.main_widget)

        self.lineEdit = Qt.QLineEdit(self)

        self.templatetype = Qt.QComboBox(self)
        self.templatetype.addItem("Tracks")
        self.templatetype.addItem("Observations")
        self.templatetype.activated[str].connect(self.combo_text)
        self.text = ""

        self.btn = Qt.QPushButton("Button", self)        
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.change_text)

        layout.addWidget(self.lineEdit)
        layout.addWidget(self.templatetype)
        layout.addWidget(self.btn)
        layout.setAlignment(Qt.Qt.AlignCenter)

    def combo_text(self,text):
        self.text = self.templatetype.currentText()

    def change_text(self):  
        self.lineEdit.setText(self.text)      

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = Qt.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]